# How to select photos in Instant Upload on Google+ while viewing them in magnified (full-screen) mode?

Tags: google-plus, photos

When using Instant Upload I usually share only some of the photos that I have taken. In most of the cases I would like to see the photo maximized to full-screen to check whether it's blurry, badly lit or if there any other problem with it before selecting it. With current interface I have to click on a photo, look at it, return to normal view and select (or skip) it.

It would be much better if I could swipe through photos in the magnified (full-screen) view and select or skip them there directly. Is it possible? If yes - how? Any plugins, extensions, GreaseMonkey scripts? If not - is there a way to do a feature request to Google+ development team? I think it could be useful to many people.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to share an individual photo there is a green Share button in the lower right of each photo. Otherwise if you want an album you need to go back to the main photos screen.

[image]